# Matching functions using Perl

Tags: regex, perl

I have a file which has many functions, as shown below, with arguments in it. I would like to    print line number of starting '{' to ending '}' of that function. So forth for all other functions.

What I tried:

```
 #!/usr/bin/perl

 format EMPLOYEE =
 @<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< @####            @####
 $func $start $end
 =======================================================
.

format EMPLOYEE_TOP =
 =======================================================
 Function                        Start            End
 =======================================================
.

select(STDOUT);
$~ = EMPLOYEE;
$^ = EMPLOYEE_TOP;

open(FILE, "<input.txt" );
while(<FILE>){
if(/^static/){
chomp;
$cols = (split(/ /))[2];
$func=$cols;
}
}
close FILE;

open(FILE, "<input.txt" );
$line;
$count = 0;
@key1=qw(static);
@key2=qw(return\sfailed);
while($line = <FILE> )
{
$count++;
foreach $k (@key1) 
{
    if ( $line =~ m/$k/ ) 
    {
          $start=$count;
          last;
    }
} 
foreach $k (@key2) 
{
  $r=0;  
    if ( $line =~ m/$k/ ) 
    {              
          last;
    }
    $end=$r+$count;
}
}
close FILE;
write;
```

Sample code in the file:

```
1.static int function1 (...,...,...,some arguments,..,..)
{
statements//
also has loops//
statements//
234. }
235.static int function2 (...,...,...,some arguments,..,..)
{
statements//
also has loops//
statements//
339. 
}
```

Output should be:

```
1 and 234 for function1.
235 and 339 for funciton2.
```

Comment: Have you looked at [MarpaX::Languages::C::AST](https://metacpan.org/pod/MarpaX::Languages::C::AST)? This is a full parser for the C programming language which builds an abstract syntax tree from C source code. Once you've done that, I imagine it's pretty easy to query the AST for the line numbers of each function declaration.

Answer (score 0):

### `{ {} {} }` Nesting: Recursion Needed

This is going to be tricky at best, but I'll give you something to try.

**Function Delimiter**

First we need to know how a function starts. What can we take as a delimiter? For instance, is `static int` always there before the function definition? And is there a guarantee that every instance of `static int` sits before a definition?

Most likely, you'll have several delimiters. We'll start with one, then add them to the list as we go.

**Recursive Regex**

Assuming `static int` is a correct delimiter, and the only one—we know this is probably not the case but we can add delimiters to the regex later—we can use a recursive regex to handle the nested braces:

```
static int [^{]*\K({(?:[^{}]++|(?1))*})
```

**Perl One-Liner**

Perhaps not the most optimized code, but this gives you a chance to try out the pattern:

```
perl -0777 -ne 'while(m/static int [^{]*\K({(?:[^{}]++|(?1))*})/g){print "$&\n";}' yourfile
```

Give that a try, then let's see if we are able to tweak.

Comment: Thanks for replying. `Static int` may not be there for all instances. It may change. I guess that from the first line of the code, it should identify a function followed by { and then } of the function.